# Multiple Projects with Multiple Repository with one solution

Tags: c#, repository, team-explorer

Is it possible to have multiple projects inside one solution or namespace but each project has its own Repository?

This is my scenario, I have a project that need to use Blob Storage, I decided to create a c# class library for shortcuts on using Blob Storage and I decided to use GitHub to host my Repository for that Class Library.

My Problem is, since my Class Library has a Repo in GitHub and my project has a different Repo in TFS.

So currently they are 2 separate solutions and want I want to do is put them in one or if I have changes on Class Library it will automatically reflect on my Project.

Any thoughts?

Comment: and why do you want this :)

Comment: For easier library management I guess, as much I do not want to switch projects or reference projects every little bit of change to my library. It sounds lazy trait but I am planning to develop multiple libraries and this will help a lot if possible

Comment: If you keep solution out of source control, and the projects in the solution  in source control, its one way to do it. But i dont know of this works nice. I dont know if full integration in VS is supported

Comment: That does not seem to work, since I need the solution in source control for my main project